# ASP.Net Ajax Javascript function taking too much time

Tags: asp.net, ajax

We are using asp.net ajax 1.1 (and can't upgrade to latest for internal known reasons). We are having a page where we call ScriptService method through ASP.Net ajax and oncallback of result, we bind that result to Html controls on the page. During testing we observed that this whole process is taking too much time. When we profiled using IE8 developer toolbar, we observed that there is one standard function from ASP.net Ajax frameworks' own JS. Function name is  function$_validateParameterType and it is the one which takes maximum time amongs others.

Is there any way we can reduce the time take by this. Is there any standard practice for such requirements.

Thanks,
Subhash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out.. Basically these functions are used mostly when we are running into debug mode. These checks are not there when running on Release mode. So i recompiled in release mode and then observed the profile output, now these functions do not appear at all..

That was very good to understand ..